# Does Object.defineProperty has access the memory address of object?

Tags: javascript, object, prototype

```
var obj = {};
Object.defineProperty(obj, "name", {
  value: "john doe"
});
console.log(obj.name); // john doe
```

How `Object.defineProperty` assign new property to the object?!

We don't call it in a new variable, so how this will assign to the main object without return new?!

Does it use memory address of variable for assigning property?!

Comment: You're passing the object you want to define the property on as the first parameter... I'm unclear as to what you're asking?

Comment: Basically similar as `obj.foo = 42;` does it. Objects are **mutable** values.

Comment: Could you explain how you think this is different from `obj["name"] = "john doe"` or `obj.name = "john doe"`? Or do those forms also cause the same confusion for you?

Comment: @JamesThorpe @apsillers I meant how does it can assign new property to `obj` when it's just passed as an arugment, functions can't change reference object and should return new object, but in this case this method change the reference object.

Comment: @rf7 Ah, so you are also confused at something like `function mutateFoo(o){ o.foo = 5; }; var obj={}; mutateFoo(obj);`, yes? Your confusion is because you think that values are immutable when passed into functions.

Comment: @apsillers I thought `mutateFoo` function just assign property to the argument, but it seems it also assign it to main `o`; i think i get my answer,  thx.

Answer (score 0):

**Yes, it does. It gets that address from `obj` when you pass it in. All of this happens behind the scenes.**

Actually, the above statement isn't *quite* correct. According to the spec, what JavaScript gets is a thing called a *reference* to the object. **Most implementations use memory addresses for references, but the spec doesn't require it, and some implementations do it differently**. For example, the Narcissus engine is written in JavaScript, but JavaScript doesn't have access to memory addresses, so Narcissus has to implement references another way.

But the way that the engine implements references doesn't really matter. What matters is that this reference gets stored in `obj` behind the scenes. **In a language like C or C++, you would have to *dereference* that in order to get to the data in the underlying object, but JavaScript does this for you automatically**. That's why you don't hear references being talked about much in JavaScript; there's usually not much need to talk about them, because of the automatic handling. But they are there.